# How can I cast an IEnumerable to an IList in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
public IList<TopicSubTopic> GetTopicSubTopics(int topicId)
{
    var topicSubTopics = _subTopicsRepository
                    .GetAll()
                    .Where(s => s.TopicId == topicId)
                    .Include(s => s.Topic)
                    .ToList();

    var topicSubTopicsSelect = from item in topicSubTopics.AsEnumerable()
        select new TopicSubTopic(
            item.TopicId,
            item.SubTopicId,
            item.Topic.Name,
            item.Name);

    return topicSubTopicsSelect;
}
```

and:

```
public partial class TopicSubTopic
{
    public TopicSubTopic(int topicId, int subTopicId, string topicName, string subTopicName)
    {
        TopicId = topicId;
        SubTopicId = subTopicId;
        TopicName = topicName;
        SubTopicName = subTopicName;
    }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public string TopicName { get; set; }
    public string SubTopicName { get; set; }
}
```

My IDE is giving me the following message:

```
Error   3   Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Models.Views.TopicSubTopic>' to 
'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Models.Views.TopicSubTopic>'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, in this case - the object returned by the query won't *be* an `IList<T>`, so a cast would fail.

The simplest fix is just to call [`Enumerable.ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx), which will create a `List<T>` from it:

```
return topicSubTopicsSelect.ToList();
```

As an aside, your `AsEnumerable()` call is pointless given that you've already called `ToList` in the previous query (although you could use `AsEnumerable()` *instead* of `ToList()` - and you don't need two separate queries anyway. I'd use:

```
return _subTopicsRepository
                .GetAll()
                .Where(s => s.TopicId == topicId)
                .Include(s => s.Topic)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(item => new TopicSubTopic(item.TopicId,
                                                  item.SubTopicId,
                                                  item.Topic.Name,
                                                  item.Name))
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your perfect answer. As always !

Comment: You could also make the AsEnumerable call after the projection.

Comment: @NunoCarmo: I suspect only after changing it to use the parameterless constructor and properties. At that point, the `AsEnumerable` would be entirely pointless.